# Can someone intercept my Messenger calls

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I want to know whether or not Facebook Messenger calls can be intercepted and listened to by hackers.

Long story, but I went on a date with a girl who I then blocked immediately afterwards due to me suspecting she was a bit of a psychopath (which the proceeding story will confirm), and then a couple of days later I was bombarded with phone calls from a private number in a robotic voice, from that girl, asking why I blocked her, making threats, saying I'd get bashed and she would kill me - my exact house address was also found by her despite me never even telling her where I lived, and she actually got someone to pull up to my address to scare me at 2:00 am when this was all happening. This was scary in and of itself, but what freaked me out even more was the fact that when I went onto my computer to make a call to my friend over Messenger, telling him what was going on, we both heard the same robotic voice sending threats, and it was on the Messenger call on my computer, not on my mobile phone.

So I am going to be concerned if they can actually listen to what I was saying and potentially hack into my Facebook and other accounts.

But if it is easy to intercept a call and send messages into that call connection without actually hearing what the parties in the call are saying, then I won't be worrying as much.

And by the way, my phone was on me the entire time we were out on a date. No way would she have been able to access it. I never told her my address. There is no way she could have installed software onto my phone. She only had my phone number, and I guess she could have found my LinkedIn page and Facebook account if she searched online, but none of which reveal my exact location. I blocked her on Snapchat and I didn't have my SnapMaps on so she couldn't have figured out my location that way as well.

Please, any clarification on the severity of this matter in terms of my internet security would really be appreciated because this is quite distressing.

Comment: If you're this worried about hackers you should probably stop using Facebook messenger all together.

Comment: `[...] we both heard the same robotic voice sending threats, and it was literally on the messenger call [...]` Sounds like a prank to me. This whole scenario sounds too fake to me

Comment: Frankly, given the details you have provided, I'd suspect your friend. You say the voice was robotic; how then do you know it was the girl? Someone "pulled up to your address". How do you know this person was sent from the girl? The fact that your friend heard the same voice leads me to suspect your friend as the simplest explanation. Or, you have misinterpretted the events you have experienced. Short answer: no, what you have described about Messenger is not possible without a ***lot*** of other things going wrong. Or, someone is pranking you.